# fluidxml | creating and xml document function

Tags: php, xml

For creating XML document I use library:

https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml

This is my function crate_xml

```
  function create_xml() {
/*****************************
 * Creating An XML Document. *
******************************/

$book = new FluidXml('book');
// or
$book = new FluidXml(null, ['root' => 'book']);

// $book is an XML document with 'book' as root node.

// The default options are:
// [ 'root'       => 'doc',      // The root node of the document.
//   'version'    => '1.0',      // The version for the XML header.
//   'encoding'   => 'UTF-8',    // The encoding for the XML header.
//   'stylesheet' => null ];     // An url pointing to an XSL file.

$booksheet = new FluidXml('book', ['stylesheet' => 'http://anydomain.org/style.xsl']);
// With PHP 7 this is valid too:
// $booksheet = FluidXml::new('book', ['stylesheet' => 'http://anydomain.org/style.xsl']);

$book->setAttribute('type', 'science')                  // It sets an attribute of the root node ('book').
     ->addChild([ 'title'  => 'The Theory Of Everything',
                     'author' => 'S. Hawking' ]);       // It creates two nodes, each one with some text inside.

echo $book->xml();                                      // Exports the xml document as a string.
echo "————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————\n";
      
  }
```

currently the result is wrong:

```
S. Hawking ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

1. What is wrong to generate correct XML document ?
2. And im not sure with this: ['stylesheet' => 'http://imnotsure.com/style.xsl']);  - How can I specify here style xsl?

Answer (score 0):

1. I ran your code, and I'm getting the correct expected output.

Are you viewing the output in a web browser? Web browsers do not know how to display , , or  tags. They will simply show the text that appears inside the elements.

2. XSL (often called XSLT) is an XML application that describes how to transform one type of XML into a different type of XML. You can find more information or examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_transformation.asp